# With Gitpod, Heroku Postgres returning Error: FATAL: role ... does not exist

Tags: postgresql, heroku, gitpod

I have a [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) app and it has a **Heroku postgres addon** attached. Im trying to connect to the remote heroku database from the [Gitpod](https://gitpod.io/) (online IDE) command line.

```
heroku pg:psql -a my-heroku-app
```

But its giving the following error:

```
--> Connecting to postgresql-rigid-XXXXX
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" does not exist
```

And I get the same error when I try to connect with the connection URL

```
psql postgres://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:ppppppppppppppppp@ec2-0000000000.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/ddddddddddddd
```

I have properly installed postgres and heroku-cli in Gitpod and they work fine.
Appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer thanks to [this](https://community.gitpod.io/t/heroku-pg-pull-and-gitpod-postgres-problem/1103) and [this](https://kevinhq.com/sync-up-heroku-postgres-to-local-postgres-on-gitpod-ide/).

`heroku pg:psql` does'nt seem to work in Gitpod. So I followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres) to import a db dump file into heroku postgres. From Gitpot command line I did

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

and got the db dump file from my local (Gitpod) database. Uploaded it to my google drive and got the publicly downloadable link. Then did

```
heroku pg:backups:restore https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?xxxxxxxx DATABASE_URL -a my-heroku-app
```

Now I have all the data in my heroku postgres database.
Cheers!